# Display delete button in gridview in gridview base on condition

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I need to display delete button based on some conditions.

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete"
                         ImageUrl="~/Images/Delete.gif" Visible="false" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**CODE BEHIND:**

```
protected void gvL3App_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{            
    DataTable dtInactiveCodes = DataRepository.getInactiveCodes();
    string[] strInactive = dtInactiveCodes.AsEnumerable()
                           .Select(row => row.Field<string>("Code")).ToArray();
    foreach (var value in strInactive)
    {
         ImageButton btnDelete= (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("btnDelete");
         btnDelete.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Here the

> `dtInactiveCodes` datatable returns values like `145`, `248`, `268`, `478` etc. Now the first column of the gridview will have these datatable returned values. I need to check these values and display that delete.

But the delete button is visible for all rows and doesn't work with the above code.

Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: I think you need to do this `if (value != string.empty){ btnDelete.Visible = true; }` inside `foreach` loop

Comment: Just do something like this, `Visible=<%# Eval("show").toString() == "true" ? "false" %>`. If it depends on the key or a value from selected table.

Comment: @VinodKumar What is `Eval("show")`?

Comment: @RahulNikate `Eval` is something you use fetch values from the bound datasource. Read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hx47hfe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for additional information.

Comment: @RahulNikate - I gave a try upon your advice and it's still the same. Is there any other way to get it work.

Comment: @Learner based on what you want to show and hide? Any specific column value or something?

Comment: @Learner I think you want to compare the value with some `dtInactiveCodes` values. I will add an answer for you.

Comment: @VinodKumar - Yes, the first column of gridview has these datatable values then I need to show the delete button.

Comment: @Learner I have given an answer. Check and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @Learner: I guess you have your answer (http://forums.asp.net/p/2052033/5914908.aspx?Re+Display+delete+button+in+gridview+in+gridview+base+on+condition)

Comment: @nadeem- I tried and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a common function `SetButtonVisibility` that will receive the `"code"` or whatever the column name that you are going to check against.

ASPX:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
<!-- I have added a additional parent Div to contain the row style... You could use or replace this with some other element -->
<div class='<%# CssClassForRow(Eval("code").ToString()) %>'>
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete"     
ImageUrl="~/Images/Delete.gif" Visible='<%# SetButtonVisibility(Eval("code").ToString()) %>' />
</div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Here just reusing your same logic to compare if this `"code"` exists in your `getInactiveCodes` and return `"true"` or `"false"`.
Code Behind:

```
public bool SetButtonVisibility(String codeValueOfRow)
{
  if(GetMatchingCodeCount(codeValueOfRow) > 0) return true;
  else return false;
}

public string CssClassForRow(String codeValueOfRow){
  //your logic here to check which CssClass to apply

  //If you want the logic to be same as above, then I suggest calling the same method.
  if(GetMatchingCodeCount(codeValueOfRow) > 0) return "highlight";
  else return "non_highlight";

  //[OR]

  //If you want to use some other logic... then...
  //A simple sample logic would be...
  if(someValue == "highlight") return "highlight";
  else return "non_highlight";
}

//Creating this method, to avoid code repetition.
public int GetMatchingCodeCount(string codeValue) {
  DataTable dtInactiveCodes = DataRepository.getInactiveCodes();
  return dtInactiveCodes.AsEnumerable().Count(row => row.Field<string>("Code")==codeValue);
}
```

Css stylesheet:

```
.highlight {
  background-color: #f00;/* Hexa-decimal color code for background*/
}
.non_highlight { /* No style here ... But you could add something here for the other rows, if you want*/ }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm getting this error `Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type string[] and int`. Also how can I apply this logic to my rowdatabound event?

Comment: @Learner Oh. My mistake... This is supposed to be `Count` rather than `Select`

Comment: @Learner You don't have to apply this logic to rowdatabound. It is done automatically at the time of row creation/bound.

Comment: I got you. I'm receiving this error now `Cannot implicitly convert type string to bool`.

Comment: @Learner Change it like this `public bool SetButtonVisibility(String codeValueOfRow)`

Comment: @RahulNikate Yea, Thanks. That should return bool probably I guess. And I updated my answer as well.

Comment: Hi @Learner It must be the other part of the code. I have updated the code. Sorry for this mess, I am not on a PC, so I could not execute the code myself. But this logic should work.

Comment: Not at all Vinod, you are actually helping me here. I should be thanking you for that. One thing, should I have to change anything in aspx to handle this error, because I am getting the same error there? `Visible='<%# SetButtonVisibility(Eval("Code").ToString())%>'`

Comment: @Learner I am glad :). No this error is not related to ASPX Page. Please tell me in which line of code you are face error with?

Comment: @Learner, Now It works. The return type should have been boolean. I have updated answer.

Comment: @VinodKumar - Is it possible to highlight these rows too?

Comment: @Learner, Sure thing... You could add a similar function that returns `String` and assign the value to `CssClass` and in your stylesheet you have to write down some style for that class.

Comment: @VinodKumar - Sorry to bug, I am really new and confused how to apply this logic to make the css work. Can you provide any sample code?

Comment: @Learner, No problem. I am happy to help. I have updated the code, with some sample styles. Please check and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    Label lbl_firstCol = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("FirstCols");
    if (lbl_firstCol.Text=="145" || lbl_firstCol.Text=="248" || lbl_firstCol.Text=="268" ||  lbl_firstCol.Text=="478")  
    {
        ImageButton btnDelete= (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("btnDelete");
        btnDelete.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: The values are dynamic and coming from a datable and I can't hardcode values like this, so the approach has to be dynamic.